# Weird behavior with Android theme using AppCompat

Tags: android, themes, android-manifest

I've a problem using AppCompat theming. I've this code:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Light" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyActionBarOverflowButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarOverflowButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_overflow</item>
</style>
```

And I want to change the theme depending on the user selection. The theme by default is the 'AppTheme', the theme the user can select is the 'AppTheme.Light'.

Now the weird thing. If I set the 'AppTheme.Light' in the manifest

> android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Light" >

The title text color is changed to white as expected, but if I set the theme programmatically

> ctx.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme_Light);

Everything changes, overflow button included, but the title text color doesn't. Why is that happening?

How can I change the title text color by setting the theme programmatically?

Thank you very much in advance!